# C++ Adding String Literal to Char Literal

Tags: c++, string, concatenation

I have a question about string concatenation in C++.

```
string str = "ab" + 'c';
cout << str << endl;

char ch = 'c';
string str1 = "ab";
string str2 = str1 + ch;
cout << str2 << endl;
```

The code produces:

```
ed before SaveGraphicsState
abc
```

Can someone explain the processing of this line: `string str = "ab" + 'c';` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your thought regarding the first line is correct, that's precisely what's happening.

There isn't any default `+` operator for literal strings like `"ab"` so what happens is the compiler takes that (as a C-style string) and uses the `const char*` pointer that points to the literal. It then takes your literal character `'c'` and promotes it to `int` with some value. This int is then added to the address of the literal and used as a C-string. Since you've exceeded the space allocated for your literal string, the results are undefined and it just printed out characters from the resulting address until it found a null.

If you want to create the string in one shot, you can help the compiler figure out that you wanted to convert to `string` first with a cast: `std::string str = std::string("ab") + 'c';`. Alternately (as seen in a separate comment) do it with concatenation which may or may not perform better. Use whichever seems clearer in your case: `std::string str = "ab"; str += 'c';`.

In the second case, you have already created a `string` and `string` has an overloaded `operator+` that does the intuitive concatenation.

Comment: Mark's answer is correct.  Note, however, that you CAN write "ab" "c" without any intervening +, and the preprocessor will concatenate them for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "ab" + 'c';
```

string literals cannot be concatenated like that. `"ab"` is an array of character, which decays into pointer (in this context) and you're adding `'c'` which is an integral to the pointer. So the pointer is advancing by the ascii value of `'c'`.

That is, the above code is equivalent to this:

```
char char * s= "ab";
string str = &s['c']; //the ascii value of 'c' acts like an index to the array.
```

I'm sure that isn't what you intended. In fact, it invokes undefined behavior, because `&s['c']` refers to a memory region which might not be in the process's address space.

---

The short form of what you actually want to do (i.e concatenation), is this:

```
string str = string("ab") + "c";
```

Comment: Or:  `string str2 = str1; str2 += ch;`

Comment: -1 `"ab"+'c'` is *not* equivalent to `"ab"['c']`. The former is a pointer, the latter is a char.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct, except the string literal isn't on stack, it's in a toolchain-specific location in memory, often in a read-only section.

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading only works where at least one of the overloaded operator's parameters is  a user-defined type (i.e. a class instance), so the + operator cannot be overloaded to add a character string and  a character. and do something sensible. At best, you will get pointer arithmetic being performed - almost certainly not what you want. The usual workround for this is an explicit conversion:

```
string s = string( "foo" ) + "bar";    // s will contain "foobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"ab"
```

Is a C-string.

```
'c'
```

Is a character.

Try:

```
string str = string("ab") + "c";
```

If you want to make it simpler, there's always:

```
string str = "ab";
str += 'c';
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::stringstream`:

```
stringstream ss;
ss << "ab" << 'c';
```

Answer (score 0):

`"ab"` is a `const char *`. `'c'` is a `char`. My guess is that `'c'` is converted to an integer, said integer is added to the address of `"ab"`, and the resulting pointer is passed to `std::string`'s constructor. You're lucky it's not miserably crashing.

See the other answers for how to do the concatenation properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think `string str = "ab" + 'c';` works something like:

```
string tmp = stirng("ab"); // implicit conversion
tmp = tmp + 'c'; // uses overloaded + operator
str = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is build into C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s("Stand back! I've got jimmies!" "DDD");
    std::cout << "Stand back! I've got jimmies!" "DDD";
}
```

output:

```
Stand back! I've got jimmies!DDD
```