# Storing a single character to Queue<string>: error

Tags: c++

I am practicing on LeetCode.

I have the following CPP code:

```
string s="abcd"; 
queue<string> q; 
string temp; 
temp=s[2]; 
queue.push(temp);
```

Error:

> Line 5: conversion from
>   '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits >::value_type {aka
>   char}' to non-scalar type 'std::__cxx11::string {aka
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string}' requested

I am wondering why this happen? I can't really change thte structure of this because temp will be growing over time (eg., temp='a'+'b'+'c';  queue.push(temp));

Comment: I think your code should be `q.push(temp)`, no?

Comment: `temp='a'+'b'+'c';` probably doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: mhmm, that too, see [Concatenating C-style string literal's in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705956/c-literal-string-concatenation)

Answer (score -1):

Read your code again ,

I am sure that you wanted to write :

```
queue.push(temp);
```

like this :

```
q.push(temp);
```