# C++ indexing "runtime error: index 98 out of bounds for type 'const char[1]'"

Tags: c++, indexing, char

I am doing a LeetCode problem in C++, and I encountered this error and am mind boggled. The error message is coming from line 8, "string current = "" + s[i];".

Also I am aware my code doesn't yet find even length palindromes.

Here's my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    string longestPalindrome(string s) {
        int len = s.length();
        string best = "";

        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            string current = "" + s[i];
            for (int j=1; j<len; j++) {
                if (i+j >= len || i-j < 0 || s[i-j] != s[i+j])
                    j = len;
                else 
                    current = s[i-j] + current + s[i+j];
            }
            if (current.length() > best.length())
                best = current;
        }

        return best;
    }
};
```

I have transferred the same exact code to Python with no issue which has made me more confused -- I guess simply I am wondering how I am possibly indexing out of bounds.

Comment: `string current = "" + s[i];` -- This is not how to concatenate strings in C++.  *I have transferred the same exact code to Python* -- Do not use python or any other language as a model in writing C++ code.  If you continue to do this, you will end up with 1) Buggy programs, 2) Inefficient programs, and 3) Programs that look weird to a C++ programmer.  That line of code is both 1) and 3).  No C++ programmer would even think of writing a line of code like that and think they are concatenating strings.

Comment: See dupe: [C++ Adding String Literal to Char Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705956/c-adding-string-literal-to-char-literal)

Answer (score 3):

The string literal `""` is a pointer type (`const char*`) and `s[i]` is a character (`char`). When you do `"" + s[i]`, then the `char` value is promoted to an integer and then pointer arithmetic takes place.

In this case it sounds like you have the letter `'b'`, which in ASCII is the value 98. So, you took your empty string literal and then offset it by 98 bytes, then used the resulting (invalid) pointer to initialize the string `current`.

For the operation to work the way you're expecting, you would need:

```
string current = string("") + s[i];
```

But that's ugly. If you want a `std::string` containing the single character `s[i]` you can construct it as follows:

```
string current(1, s[i]);
```

Note also that `string best = "";` is redundant. A `std::string` is default-constructed to an empty string, so `string best;` is perfectly fine.

---

Regarding the problem that it appears you're trying to solve, you are sort of going about it in a long-winded way.

All you really need to do is count the number of each character that appears in the string. Then, for each character that has an even number of occurrences, include that in your result. If there are any characters with an odd number of occurrences, then add one of them to the result.

This results in a time complexity of O(N) where `N` is the length of the string. That's much more efficient than your O(N<sup>2</sup>) approach.

Example:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <climits>
#include <string>

using namespace std;  //<-- this is a bad habit...
```

```
// <... SNIP ...>

string longestPalindrome(string s) {
    // Count and collect characters with even number of occurrences
    array<int, 1U << CHAR_BIT> counts{};
    string even;
    even.reserve(s.size() / 2);
    for (unsigned char c : s) {
        if ((++counts[c] % 2) == 0) even.push_back(c);
    }

    // Find a character with odd number of occurrences
    auto odd_iter = find_if(
        counts.begin(), counts.end(),
        [](int count) {
            return count % 2 != 0;
        });

    // Concatenate even chars, optional odd char, and reversed even chars
    string result;
    result.reserve(s.size());
    result.append(even);
    if (odd_iter != counts.end()) {
        result.push_back((unsigned char)std::distance(counts.begin(), odd_iter));
    }
    result.append(even.rbegin(), even.rend());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Or `string current = s.substr(i, 1);`