# I want to concatenate more characters and strings to an existing string in c++

Tags: c++, string, concatenation, push-back

```
string s;
s += "#" + ',';  //give error
s += "#" + ",";  //give error
s += to_string(23) + ',';   //no error
```

What is the proper way to concatenate new characters and strings to an existing string using + operator and when will it throw error? Can someone also shed light how append() and push_back() are different from "+" and which is the most optimal way?

Comment: If you need to concatenate lots of small strings, consider using an `std::stringstream` instead, which does not have this footgun and does not generate tons of intermediate copies.

Comment: `"#"` is a character array, not `std::string`, so it doesn't overload `+` nor has any methods. But the failing lines are not something you would actually write when you can do `s += "#,"`.

Comment: @Botje `stringstream` has its own footguns, starting with persistent formatting state. We have better tools now, I'd recommend `std::format_to` a `std::string`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  Why isn't "#," considered a character array if "#" is ?

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: Btw `s += "#" + ','; ` [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/c1W6K1bcK)

Comment: @AadharJain `"#,"` and `"#"` are both character arrays, but `"#" + ","` and `"#" + ','` are not.

Comment: And `s += "#" + ',';` is equivalent to (assuming ASCII encoding) `s += &"#"[0] + 44;`; it adds the numerical encoding of `','` to a pointer to the first element of `"#"`. ([Example](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec71a6962c649656))

Comment: @HolyBlackCat is `format_to` still recommended over a stringstream if lots of control flow is intermingled with the string generation? For example generation of a comma-separated string

Comment: @AadharJain `"#,` is also a character array. `string += array` is fine. Generally, at least one operand must be `std::string`. If neither is one, there's no way for `string`'s overloaded operators to kick in.

Comment: @Botje In my humble opinion, iostreams must die. But there is no official guidance, of course.

Answer (score 7):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement `s += "#" + ',';`.

The problem is that `operator+` has **higher precedence** than `operator+=`. This means that `s += "#" + ','` is **equivalent** to writing

```
s += ("#" + ','); //same as s += "#" + ','
```

Now, `"#"` is a **string literal** of type `const char [2]` while `','` is a **character literal** of type `char`. So basically, in this case you're [trying to add a string literal to a char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705956/c-adding-string-literal-to-char-literal). Now, when you do this, **string literal decays to a `const char*`** and the character literal is promoted to `int`.

Essentially, this adds a `const char*` to an `int`. The result of this is used as an operand of `+=`.

More about this can be read at [C++ Adding String Literal to Char Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705956/c-adding-string-literal-to-char-literal)

---

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement `s += "#" + ",";`.

In this case also the statement `s += "#" + ",";` is **equivalent** to writing:

```
s += ("#" + ","); //same as s += "#" + ","
```

due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

But in this case **both the operand to** `operator+` **are of type** `const char [2]`.

So essentially, you're **trying to add two string literals here**. But there is no overloaded `operator+` that takes two string literals or `const char*` so this gives the mentioned error:

```
 error: invalid operands of types 'const char [2]' and 'const char [2]' to binary 'operator+'
```

---

##### Solution

There are several ways to solve this one of which include to add suffix `s` after the string literal as shown below:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
s += "#"s + ","s;  //works correctly now
```

Another way is to explicitly write `std::string("#")`.

Comment: so, if you can't avoid it, write ```s += std::string("#") + ",";```. This way you're concatenating the const char* "," to a std::string, which is defined.

Comment: @KungPhoo Yes, I've added the explanation for the second case(`s += "#" + ","`) also. Check out the updated answer. In this second case(`s += "#" + ","`) both operands to `operator+` are of type `const char[2]` but there is no overloaded `operator+` that takes these two operands so we get the mentioned error as also explained in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

C++ now<sup>(*)</sup> allows *litteral strings*.

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

string s = "foo";
s += "#"s + ","s;
```

Not only this code raises no error, but it produces the expected output.

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Since C++14, according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s)

Answer (score 0):

> Which is the most optimal way?

If you mean by optimal <-> convenience to do the concatenation of `char`s and/or string literals and/or `std::string`,  is a variadic template function that does it as follows:

```
template<typename... Args>
std::string concatenate(Args&&... args) {
   return (std::string{} + ... + std::forward<Args>(args)); // require C++17
}
```

[See a live demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3MYq4rGqv)

You don't need to worry now about what you pass/ type (i.e. `const char`, `char[]`, `char` or `std::string`). The function will return the concatenated string for you.

```
char arr[]{ "..." };
std::cout << concatenate('H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', " World", "!"s, arr); // prints Hello World!...
```